# Solve the recurrence relation where $S_n=3S_{n-1}+3;S_0=10$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence relation where $S_n=3S_{n-1}+3;S_0=10$

I tried using the iterative method but I am completely lost. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Replace $S_n=a\times 3^n+b$ in the recurrence relation and try to find $a$ and $b$, noting that $S_0=10$

Comment: Alt. hint: look for a $\,k\,$ such that the relation can be written as $S_n+k=3\left(S_{n-1}+k\right)$. Comparing with the original, it follows that $\,2k=3\,$, then $\,S_n+\frac{3}{2}=3\left(S_{n-1}+\frac{3}{2}\right)\,$ means that $\,S_n+\frac{3}{2}\,$ is a GP.

Comment: What does "solve" mean here?

Comment: I thought it meant to write in the recurrence relation in a simplified form, in terms of n, so that we can easily compute the nth term without having to calculate the ( n-1)th term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look for $a $ such that $(S_n+a)$ is geometric.

Put $u_n=S_n+\frac {3}{2} $.

then

$$u_n=3u_{n-1}$$
and

$$u_n=3^nu_0$$
with
$$u_0=S_0+\frac {3}{2}=\frac {23}{2} $$
finally

$$S_n=\frac {23}{2}3^n-\frac {3}{2} .$$

Comment: this makes sense but can you tell me how did you come up with the value for $u_n$ in the beginning

Comment: @nova_star It is the value of $a $.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\begin{align}S_n&=3S_{n-1}+3\\&=3^2S_{n-2}+3^2+3\\&=3^3S_{n-3}+3^3+3^2+3\\&=\cdots\\&=3^nS_{n-n}+\sum_{k=1}^n 3^k\\&=10(3^n)+\frac{3^{n+1}-3}2\end{align}$$ so $$\boxed{S_n=\frac{23}2\cdot3^n-\frac32}$$

Comment: can you tell me how did you get from $3^k$ series to ${3/2}^{n+1)-3/2$?

Comment: @nova_star It is a geometric serie that is missing its first summant.

Comment: We have $$\sum_{k=1}^n3^k=-1+\sum_{k=0}^n3^k=-1+\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

solve the homogeneous equation $$s_n=3s_{n-1}$$ with $$s_n=q^n$$ we get
$$s_n=C3^{n-1}$$ now you will Need a special solution of the inhomogeneous equation and using the equation $$s_0=10$$ we get $$s_n=\frac{1}{2}(23\cdot 3^n-3)$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the formal power series $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n z^n$. Multiplying both sides of the recurrence relation by $z^n$ and summing over $n$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty S_nz^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3S_{n-1}z^n + 3\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n.
$$
Writing this in terms of $f(z)$ we have
$$
f(z) - 10 = 3zf(z) + \frac{3z}{1-z},
$$
and solving for $f(z)$ yields
$$
f(z) = \frac{10}{1-3z} + \frac{3z}{(1-z)(1-3z} = \frac{10-7z}{(1-z)(1-3z)}.
$$
Partial fraction decomposition yields
$$
f(z) = \frac{23}2 \left(\frac1{1-3z}\right) -\frac32\left(\frac1{1-z}\right) ,
$$
and hence
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{23}2\cdot 23^n - \frac32  \right)z^n.
$$
It follows that
$$
S_n = \left(\frac{23}2\right)^n - \frac32.
$$

Comment: Is it $23^n $ ? sure?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I meant $\left(\frac{23}2\right)^n$, thanks for pointing that out.